# LinqToEntity - updating all records

Tags: c#, sql, .net, linq, entity-framework

I'm going to modify only one property in all records of a one database table and I don't want to materialize all of the records (as it is done by method ToList() and then iterating through the collection of entities, and then commit).
I use EF (5.0, NET 4.0) and linq (thus LinqToEntity).

I mean I want to find the linq counterpart for the following SQL statement:

```
UPDATE Table
SET Property='NewValue';
```

Is it possible?

Comment: You cannot do this with plain EF, you should take a look to EF Extensions http://efe.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run SQL code through the context without using db.SaveChanges:

```
using(var db = new YourDbContext())
{
    db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("UPDATE TABLE SET PROPERTY='NewValue'");
}
```

If you need to parameterize the value(s) then you can do that as well:

```
db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("UPDATE TABLE SET PROPERTY=@Property",
    new SqlParameter("@Property", someVariable));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ExecuteSqlCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679456%28v=vs.113%29.aspx):

```
contex.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("UPATE Table SET Property = @p0", value)
```